# Lagrange multipliers like quesiton

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose $f,g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuously differentiable functions and $\nabla g \neq 0$ everywhere. If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point such that
$$f(x_0,y_0) = \inf \{f(x,y) : g(x,y) = 0\},$$
then there exists some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\nabla f(x_0,y_0) = \lambda\nabla g(x_0,y_0).$$

I'm guessing you're supposed to use the inverse function theorem at $(x_0,y_0)$ somehow, but I have no clue how. I honestly don't even really see why this should be true, since $g$ isn't necessarily zero at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Here's some geometric intuition that might help you find the proof.  Note that the $\nabla g$ is going to be normal to the curve $g(x,y)=0$.  Project $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ on to the tangent to $g(x,y)=0$ at $(x_0,y_0)$.  If it is not zero, then moving in that direction will increase the value of $f$, and moving in the opposite direction will decrease the value of $f$, so it can't be a minimum ( or maximum ).  Therefore $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ is normal to the tangent line of $g$, so it is a multiple of $\nabla g(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not seeing why $\nabla g (x_0,y_0)$ should be normal to the zero level set. I also don't know what you mean by the tangent to $g(x,y) = 0$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. If $g(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$ how does $g(x,y) = 0$ have a tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$?Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sure.  The gradient is normal to any constant level set, since moving in any direction with a component in the direction of the gradient would change the value of $g$.  $g(x_0,y_0)$ should be $0$ by definition.  Your definition is actually kind of strange; There could be lots of points where $f$ is equal to $inf\{f(x,y) : g(x,y)=0\}$ that are not on $g(x,y)=0$, but those points are not interesting.  The point is to find an infimum on the level set $g(x,y)=0$.  That should be $(x_0,y_0)$ by definition.